# How does adyen offer cashout if this is not allowed by Visa?

Tags: credit-card

Adyen defines cashback and cashout in the following way:
https://docs.adyen.com/point-of-sale/cashback-and-cash-out

> With their purchase (cashback).
> Without a purchase (cash out).

The [Visa Transaction Acceptance Device Guide](https://technologypartner.visa.com/Download.aspx?id=573) says: "A response that the cash back amount is equal to the total transaction
amount (this is not allowed)."

So how can adyen support a cash out? In a cashout the cash back amount would be equal to the total transaction. Did I somehow misunderstand the documentation? Or perhaps cashout is allowed but not for visa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full quote from https://docs.adyen.com/point-of-sale/cashback-and-cash-out is:

> Shoppers using an EFTPOS (Electronic Funds Transfer at Point Of Sale)
> card in Australia can obtain a small amount of cash from their
> account, either:
>
> - With their purchase (cashback).
> - Without a purchase (cash out).

So indeed not possible with Visa or Mastercard, only with an EFTPOS card.

Comment: good point and weird that this feature is not more generally available. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the mastercard documentation and found this:

> Merchants in South Africa that have received prior approval from their
> acquirers may offer a purchase with cash back transaction with or
> without an accompanying purchase to any cardholder for intra-country
> transactions. PIN verification must be obtained for each purchase with
> cash back transaction without an accompanying purchase.

So according to this mastercard allows cashback without accompanying purchase. It seems then that not allowing this is either VISA specific or I misunderstood the documentation.